# Is a jbyteArray a jobject (i.e.: as a parameter to DeleteLocalRef)?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

In JNI, is a jbyteArray considered a jobject?  I.e.: if I have some long-running C++ code, can I use code like the following to release the object reference?

```
JNIEnv* env;

jobject getJavaObj(bool useArray) {
    if (useArray) {
        jbyteArray dataArray = env->NewByteArray(getDataSize());
        env->SetByteArrayRegion(dataArray, 0, getDataSize(), dataPtr);
        return static_cast<jobject>(dataArray)
    } else {
        jobject javaByteBuffer = env->NewDirectByteBuffer(dataPtr, getDataSize());
        return javaByteBuffer;
    }
}

// ...
jobject theData = getJavaObj(true);
// ... Code to use theData jobject goes here...
env->DeleteLocalRef(theData); // Will this cause any issues?
```

The JDK's jni.h include file seems to indicate that this would be a correct assumption, but I can't find much on the web to back up this assumption:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
class _jobject {};
...
class _jarray : public _jobject {};
typedef _jbyteArray *jbyteArray;
#else
....
#endif
```

**Background:**

I have some JNI code which has a memory leak that I'm trying to pin down.  The total process size keeps increasing, but JConsole says the JVM's heap memory usage and non-heap usage are remaining fairly constant.  So my conclusion is that the leak must be in the raw C++ itself, or in the JNI code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, yes `jbyteArray` is a `jobject` and yes, you can explicitly tell GC to free it  by calling `DeleteLocalRef`. Otherwise it would be freed automatically when the current JNI call returns to JVM. **But i don't think it will help you**. By using `NewByteArray` and `NewDirectByteBuffer` you are allocating *JVM heap, not native memory*. It must be so, otherwise GC could not reach it (and calling `DeleteLocalRef` wouldn't make sense). But you say that JVM heap usage is fairly constant. If the java process memory usage is growing but not JVM heap, then you got problem in your *native allocation*. Where is your `dataPtr` coming from? Do you deallocate it properly? Isn't there some other significant allocation in your "long running code"? Not necessarily tied to JNI at all...

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  And yes, I do realize (as I stated above) that there are quite possibly leak issues in my native code, but I'm trying to "cover all my bases" by making sure I clean up my references.  As a note, it does appear NewDirectByteBuffer can allocate memory outside the JVM heap (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#direct, https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1546985&tstart=765).  But you are absolutely correct on NewByteArray.

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct. I was so focused on pointing you in the right direction that i have shoveled both allocation functions under one roof. My bad.